# How to deserialize XML and get value of specific key after given element

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have `XML` like:

```
<campaign>
    <id  type="integer">123</id>
    <name>campaign1</name>
    <description>campaign1</description>
    <flights  type="array">
        <flight>
            <id  type="integer">987</id>
            <name>flight1</name>
        </flight>
        <flight>
            <id  type="integer">3254</id>
            <name>flight2</name>
        </flight>
    </flights>
</campaign>
```

I want to fetch data under Flights node. I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` of `2.8.0` version.

I'm using code:
Flight class

```
@Getter
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "flight")
public class Flight {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
}
```

Test class:

```
ObjectMapper flightMapper = new XmlMapper();
flightMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Flight flight = flightMapper.readValue(xmlString, Flight.class);
```

But this always gives me id and name of campaign. Output that I get is

```
id = 123
name = campaign1
```

I also tried using:

```
List<Flight> flights = flightMapper.readValue(xmlString, new TypeReference<List<Flight>>() {});
```

But this always returns `null` value.
Can anyone please help me? I want to fetch `List<Flight>` object with `id` and `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create wrapper class:

```
class Campaign {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "flights")
    private List<Flight> flights;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

After that you can deserialise it as below:

```
List<Flight> flights = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlFile, Campaign.class).getFlights();
```

Comment: This worked with little change. Just added "@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "flights")" before declaring List<Flight> flights

Comment: @DevSolanki, that's strange a little bit. In version `2.9.9` it works without extra annotation. Which version do you use?

Comment: I use version 2.8.0